# Error deploying SSIS package (Oracle connector)

Tags: oracle, deployment, ssis

I am currently working in a local environment (Both my SQL Server and Visual Studio instance is on the same laptop

I have built a SSIS package that takes data from Oracle and loads data onto a SQL Server

The package executes properly through Visual Studio 2019, but will not allow me to publish to SQL Server

I get the following error

> Failed to deploy the project. Fix the problems and try again
> later.:Unable to create the type with the name 'ORACLE'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you debug code or settings that you cannot see?

Comment: I think it might be due to me having a 64 bit version of SQL server installed. I just don’t know how to get it to work

Comment: So what is the bit architecture of the other components - SSIS, Visual Studio, and the oracle client?

Comment: SSIS (32bit) Visual Studio 2019 (32 bit) SQL Server 2017 (64 bit) Oracle Server (Unknown)

Comment: What type of connection between the clients and the databases themselves?  If it is a tcp (network) connection - even if all on the same server - the architecture of the databases won't matter.  But the architecture between SSIS, VS, and the database _client_ stack must all be the same.  But again, if you don't share your code/configuration, all we have is a very vague error message with no context.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the same issue by modifying the Project Configuration Properties which I usually forget whenever I create a new solution.
Since we run SQL Server 2014 I had to align the TargetServerVersion:

[Project Property Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrUEg.png)